# whenever i execute the programm i got an error called sub or function are not defined

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub count_of_rc()
    Set wbi = ActiveWorkbook
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
    tr = Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    tc = Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Columns.Count
End Sub
```

it is showing that the subscript is out of range

Comment: This code works on my end. Which line produces the error?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `Private` keyword from your code.